# Three Equation System

Tags: calculus

I'm getting into economics currently but I'm quite stuck with an apparently rather simple problem within a problem.

I'm required to solve a three equation system within a problem consisting of the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{L}_{,x_1} &=& 2x_1x_2 −\lambda p_1 = 0  \\
\mathcal{L}_{,x_2} &=& x_1^2 -\lambda p_2 = 0 \\
\mathcal{L}_{,\lambda} &=& m - p_1 x_1 - p_2 x_2 = 0 
\end{eqnarray}

Note that the numbers after $x$ or $p$ as in $x_1$ or $p_2$ indicate different goods and prices.

I'm supposed to solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ and this is supposed to be the solution

$$
x_1 = 2m/3p_1 \\ 
_2 = m/3p_2 
$$

Unfortunately I have no clue and I m all out of ideas as in how to get there.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Flo

Comment: Hint: Express $\lambda$ in terms of $x_1$ and then substitute it into the 1st equation.

Answer (score 0):

For solving equations, one should say exactly what the variables are, and what are given constants. This includes to say over which domain we want to solve the given equations. It looks like, but you haven't said so, that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, with $\lambda,m,p_1,p_2>0$ as given constants. If so, you can start substituting, say, with $\lambda=2x_1x_2/p_1$. Here you need $p_1\neq 0$. Then the second equation becomes
$$
(p_1x_1 - 2p_2x_2)x_1=0.
$$
Now we have two cases. First, $x_1=0$ would imply that $\lambda=0$, and $m=p_2x_2$. Assuming $p_2\neq 0$ we obtain $x_2=m/p_2$.

Secondly, we obtain
$$
p_1x_1 - 2p_2x_2=0,\; p_1x_1 + p_2x_2 - m=0.
$$
Substracting both equations gives $3p_2x_2=m$.